# how to differentiate with color values from two columns both on x-axis with matplotlib python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to do a plot that has on x axis dates and on y some values. But I have two columns as dates. I would like to highlight the date of the second column with a dot of another color. Is it possible?

```html
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |      Date1       |      Date2       |      value       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |    2008-05-14    |    2010-03-28    |        5         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |    2005-12-07    |    2010-03-28    |        3         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |    2008-10-27    |    2010-03-28    |        6         |
```

```
df1 = df[df['ID']== 1]
df1= df1.sort_values(by='Date1')  

date = df1['Date1']
res = df1['values']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(date, res, 'o-')
```

Comment: What about `ax.plot(chol2['Date2'], chol2['value'], 'o-', color='green')`?

Comment: yees, it sounds good. And what if I want to plot a vertical line at the Date2?

Comment: `ax.axvline(df1['Date2'][0])`?

Comment: it's perfect, thank you very much!!